# How to separate a comma separated name field in MySQL in to first name, middle name, last name and fullname?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I have a `NAME` column and the data is stored like this in a MySql database:

> Doe,John P

I would like to break it out into `FNAME` `LNAME` `MNAME` and `FULLNAME`.

If I don't want to tamper with the SQL table, should I create a view?

I know how to fix it in PHP with a function but I would rather the processing be done on the database server than the application server.

This is what I have so far. I thinking I need a compound query or something similar.

```
SELECT Name
       , SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,',',-1) As FNAME
       , SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,',',1)  As LNAME
       , SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name,' ',1)  As MNAME 
  FROM people;
```

I'm having trouble grabbing the middle name and doing what I think should be `CONCAT` function to get `FULLNAME`.

It would be great if there was a way (maybe a conditional) to handle names in the database that didn't have middle names. (i.e. DOE,JOHN).

Comment: Check out this question [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns).

Answer (score 1):

A view is a fine way to get the results you want for future queries.  The defining query would be:

```
SELECT Name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ',', -1), ' ', 1)  As FNAME,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ',', 1)  As LNAME,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1)  As MNAME
FROM people;
```

This will work assuming that the format is *exactly* correct as you describe it in the table.  Small changes -- such as no middle name or a space after the comma -- would make the syntax more complicated.